# how to read the second stream at UVC?

Tags: uvc, uvcvideo

the UVC camera have 4 nodes

cam (usb-fd800000.usb-1.1):
/dev/video9
/dev/video10
/dev/video15
/dev/video16

the cam have two video streams, want to preview the two video at the same time .

using UVC ,preview the second video stream.